# Code behind can`t find element in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an element in my XAML called Tasklst which I was able to reference it in my code-behind without a problem. However, when I introduced a tab control (as shown below) and moved my Tasklst inside a DataTemplate, suddenly my code-behind was telling me that Tasklst cannot find it. How do I reference it now?

```
<dx:DXTabControl x:Name="TabControl"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Sequences}"
                 SelectionChanged="TabControl_OnSelectionChanged"
                 SelectedItem="">
    <dx:DXTabControl.View>
        <dx:TabControlMultiLineView HeaderLocation="Bottom" />
    </dx:DXTabControl.View>

    <!--Header-->
    <dx:DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dx:DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplate>

    <!--Content-->
    <dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:DxTaskList x:Name="Tasklst" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>

</dx:DXTabControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

DataTemplate is the Problem here ...

you can do something like this

```
(DxTaskList)TabControl.Template.FindName("Tasklst", TabControl);
```